# same package name and class name with framework

Tags: java, android

for example. In my source code, I have a class named Camera.java in the package android/hardware. But In android. there is also a class Camera.java with same package name.

My Camera.java is designed by myself for example it has some extral function and I call these function in my source code.

I build successfully in Android Studio but When I run it on a Android device. the app crash and stacktrace shows that it can not find these function.

My question is which class my app will use in Android device. In my app storage or in system/framework/

Comment: post your error log please.

Comment: Have you tried refactoring your `Camera` to , e.g. `MyCamera` or anything?

Comment: Show The Error Log, You have to extend the class and and override the method which you want to change, By giving same it will not work ,  use base.methodname() to call the base class implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some more functionality into inbuilt `function` `Camera` then use `inheritance`, `method overriding`, `method overloding` functionality of `OOP`.

In case you want to define it separately then use rather than `inbuilt class` name as it causes to generate `ambiguity` problem